# Claim 835 to PDF

Tags: c#, python, pdf

I have a case where I am receiving some .835 files. I have searched for a bit, but need a solution (python, c#, etc) to take these files and export them as a pdf. Has anyone come across a library or free command line application as I need to be able to batch call this program.

In my research I have come across TigerShark(python), but without understanding some of the fields I am at a lost on how to generate a clean pdf from the file.

Comment: OpenEMR suite might have such tool(s), and code is free

Comment: While OpenEMR is a nice solution, it doesnt support batch operations and converting record to PDF.

Comment: Taking a file that consists of data and exporting it as "PDF" is not the full definition. What "PDF"? What "look" do you want and what additional information would you like on the page? What page size do you want? Your question is incomplete as you do not express how you want to represent the data in the PDF.

Comment: Downvote? Clearly stated in the question is the question of converting .835 files to PDF. Supplemented library points to EDI and Claim transactions. Yes, some knowledge on the subject would be required to understand exporting the claim to a pdf.

Comment: I would guess Kevin tried to point out that there is no one definitive solution to convert something like .835 into PDF. You have to have some formatting directives in the spirit of XSL-FO or stylesheets to place elements and define look&feel. Anyway, to me looks like going via XML (recover structure but not look&feel) and then XML->PDF where you define formatting might be the best route. Good luck

Comment: Understandable, after digging into the source code [TigerShark](https://github.com/sbuss/TigerShark/) ended up being my solution. Looking into the message structure [here](https://github.com/sbuss/TigerShark/blob/master/tigershark/X12/message/__init__.py) I was able to get the transaction items and get it into a PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understandable, after digging into the source code [TigerShark](https://github.com/sbuss/TigerShark/) ended up being my solution. Looking into the message structure [here](https://github.com/sbuss/TigerShark/blob/master/tigershark/X12/message/__init__.py) I was able to get the transaction items and get it into a PDF.